# Declare function that takes generic type that conform to “can be multiplied” in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How to declare function that takes generic type that conform to “can be multiplied” in Swift ?

For example :

```
 func sq <T: "Can be multipied">(x: T) -> T {
    return x*x
 }
```

So that I could square Float, Double, CGFloat etc ... It this possible at all ?

Comment: There is (as far as I know) no predefined protocol for "multipliable" . The code in this question shows how you can define one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666008/generic-custom-operator-functions-a-curious-case-of-a-bad-instruction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your own protocol like this:

```
protocol Multipliable {
   func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

func sq<T: Multipliable>(value:T) -> T {
  return value * value
}

extension Int: Multipliable {}
extension Double: Multipliable {}

sq(10)   // -> 100
sq(10.0) // -> 100.0
```

I believe you have to extend every class that you want to conform to this protocol, I don't know of any way for it to work without using an `extension`.

Here's an interesting article on the implementation of the `Equatable` protocol:

http://nshipster.com/swift-default-protocol-implementations/